# Javascript : Click button when time reach xx:xx:xx

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasemonkey and I want a code that if the time is 00:00:05 will click a button, this is the timer :

```
<dt id="temps">Time remaining:0:35:22</dt>
```

and this is the button :

```
<input class="Button1" type="button" style="padding: 10px" value="OK!">
```

This is what I made ( I'm an extreme noob in JS ) :

```
function clickbid() {
    if document.getElementById('temps') = 00:00:05;
    document.getElEmentsByClassName('Button1').click();
    else {
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Scripting an eBay auction sniper?

Comment: No, and is not even a bot, just something will help me to click a button in one website.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Wancj/2/

```
function clickbid() {
    var timeData = document.getElementById('temps').firstChild.data,
        timeLeft = timeData.substr(timeData.length-7, 7);

   if (timeLeft == '0:00:05'){
        debug.innerHTML = "Bid foo";
    }else{
         debug.innerHTML = "aint time yet dawg!";   
    }
}
```

This should at least get you on the right path.